# Chat search turning up messages moved to another room

Tags: bug, search, chat

A few messages from the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room which had been moved to another room are, nonetheless, showing up when searching SOCVR.  Stranger still, the transcripts permalink to their location in the new room.

This seems to be specific to these messages, as messages are moved from that room all the time, with no ill effects.

To narrow things down, search for ["why does my async program"](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=why+does+my+async+program&user=&room=41570). This search is in room 41570 (the SOCVR graveyard).

Follow the permalink for the resulting entry, though - it takes you directly to room 90230. Not even a redirect, that's how it's showing up in the search results.

Comment: Cross site duplicate: [Some chat messages moved to another room still appear in original room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303888)